# jquery skip a block

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery game that you can view here [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/DHPQT/)

The game starts by you entering a number in a text field. 
then you click the play button.

After clicking the play button a set of square appear each rotating random numbers, click on the square that has your number to build up your score, miss 3 times and you are done.

I added the game to my site, you can view it here [link text](http://www.gamerholic.com/pickanumber.php)

the problem I'm having is that my site members will just keep the cursor on one box and wait for their number to appear in that one box. Which ruins the game.
Is there a way to make it so they can't click on the same box more than once in a row. They'll have to go click another box before they can come back to this one.

here's my complete script

```
    var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;

function IsNumeric(n) {
return !isNaN(n);
}

$("#getit").click(function() {
var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;
$('#hitcount').text(0);
$('#misscount').text(0);

$('#message').hide(100);  
var li = [],
    intervals = 0,
    n = parseInt($('#MyNumber').val());

var intervalId = -1;
if (IsNumeric(n)) {
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        li[intervals++ % li.length].text(Math.random() > .1 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + n) + (n / 2)) : n).attr('class', '')    ;
    }, <?php echo $time ?>);
}

$('#randomnumber').empty();

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    li.push($('<li />').appendTo('#randomnumber'));
}

$('#randomnumber').delegate("li", "click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
            if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
                $this.addClass('correct');
                $('#hitcount').text(++hitCount);
            } else {
                $this.addClass('wrong');
                $('#misscount').text(++missCount);
            }

            //New code If the missCount > 3 stop the game and save the value
            if(missCount>=<?php echo $limit ?>){
               clearInterval(intervalId);
               $('#randomnumber').undelegate("li", "click");
                // Use a ajax request to save the values

$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'FBhighscore_hwnd.php',
dataType : 'json',
data: {
tgameid: $('#tgameid').val(),MyNumber: $('#MyNumber').val(),totalHits: hitCount
},
success : function(data){
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
.text(data.msg).show(500);
if (data.error === true)
$('#loginForm').show(500);
else
$('#send').hide(500);  
},
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
.text('There was an error.').show(500);
$('#loginForm').show(500);
}
});

            }
        }

        $this.addClass('clicked');
    });

return false;
});
```

Comment: So what problem are you having with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `.one()` to bind your click events, instead of `.click()`?  Here's the documentation for it: http://api.jquery.com/one/

If you bind the click event with `.one()` then you could ensure that the function will only be triggered once.  Then, inside that function, rebind the events for all *other* boxes, thus ensuring that they have to click another box before click the same one again.

Alternately:

Use a combination of `.hover()` and `setTimeout()` (and possibly [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)) to disable a box when the user hovers their mouse over it for too long.

**EDIT**

Have a look at this modified version of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/9ffTA/

Clicking on the same box twice in a row is disallowed.  Hopefully you can use that as a guide.

Comment: tried all, nothing. Not sure if I'm using them in the right way

Comment: John, I have updated my answer with a link to a modified version of your demo which follows my first suggestion.

Comment: thank you, I had to work a bit for that one but I got it working. The delagate just wouldn't work so now instead of undelegate I hide hid the div.

Comment: Now how about a count down timer? I think that's the last piece missing in the game.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your click you can mark that box as "locked" and just disable it until the next click.

Answer (score 0):

That will not solve your problem. The user can still just move to another box and wait for their number to appear in that box. I just did it myself on your site. I don't believe there is a solution to your problem with the current game design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with clicking, but with scoring.

Your proposed solution doesn't really defeat "waiting" as a strategy, as [Drew points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189909/jquery-skip-a-block/4189944#4189944).  To really fix waiting, you need to give it a penalty.

Were it my game, I'd have three scoring metrics — correctly clicked boxes (what you're currently calling "hits"), incorrectly clicked boxes (... "misses"), and unclicked boxes (not in your current game).  In other words, if my number is 5 and a box containing a 5 fades (is replaced by another number) before I click it, that's counted against me.

With this scoring system in place, anyone who simply hovers over a box and waits — even if they switch boxes between clicks — will watch their score get lower and lower as they miss boxes.

Comment: I'm going to add a count down timer, 3 mins max. that should eliminate the waiting problem.